# Files.walkFileTree leaking directory descriptors with custom FileVisitor

Tags: java, file

I came across a weird bug in my app. I already solved it by a workaround, but I'm still curious why is this bug happening.

Below is given an example of a custom FileVisitor that is deleting empty directories it walks through. If the directories are not empty, and it still walks over those directories, it will leak directory descriptors. If I use `lsof` with the app's PID, it will show a bunch of descriptors pointing to the same few directories, the ones it walks over.

```
private String getOldestFile() {
    fileVisitor.clearOldestFile();

    try {
        // FIXME: this was throwing FileSystemException: Too many open files after some time running. Leaking file descriptors!!
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(csvPath), fileVisitor);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return fileVisitor.getOldestFile().toString();
}

class CustomFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private Path oldestFile = null;

    Path getOldestFile() {
        return oldestFile;
    }

    void clearOldestFile() {
        oldestFile = null;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (attrs.isDirectory())
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;

        if (oldestFile == null)
            oldestFile = file;

        if (oldestFile.compareTo(file) > 0)
            oldestFile = file;

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        if (dir.equals(Paths.get(csvPath)))
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;

        if (Files.list(dir).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == 0)
            Files.delete(dir); // throws an exception if folder is not empty -> mustn't delete folder with files

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

CustomFileVisitor is created only once, in the outer class and the function is called periodically like `filename = getOldestFile();`

EDIT: Posting `lsof -p {PID}` output. At the beginning, I find out PID as in [this](https://maxrohde.com/2012/12/13/java-get-process-id-three-approaches/).

This is what the `lsof -p {PID}` output looks like, only there is thousands of those lines. "/home/leon/Development/data/" is the input to the Files.walkFileTree.

```
java    14965 leon  285r      DIR                8,2     4096  1970798 /home/leon/Development/data/2017
java    14965 leon  286r      DIR                8,2     4096  1970799 /home/leon/Development/data/2017/10
java    14965 leon  287r      DIR                8,2     4096  1970799 /home/leon/Development/data/2017/10
java    14965 leon  288r      DIR                8,2    36864  1970800 /home/leon/Development/data/2017/10/17
java    14965 leon  289r      DIR                8,2    36864  1970800 /home/leon/Development/data/2017/10/17
java    14965 leon  290r      DIR                8,2     4096  1970798 /home/leon/Development/data/2017
java    14965 leon  291r      DIR                8,2     4096  1970798 /home/leon/Development/data/2017
java    14965 leon  292r      DIR                8,2     4096  1970799 /home/leon/Development/data/2017/10
java    14965 leon  293r      DIR                8,2     4096  1970799 /home/leon/Development/data/2017/10
java    14965 leon  294r      DIR                8,2    36864  1970800 /home/leon/Development/data/2017/10/17
java    14965 leon  295r      DIR                8,2    36864  1970800 /home/leon/Development/data/2017/10/17
```

EDIT 2: I've managed to isolate the problem to this line: `Files.list(dir).collect(Collectors.toList()).size() == 0`. Shouldn't this be garbage collected?

Comment: There is no code here that opens any of the files, so why does it create file descriptors? Could you post a snippet of the `lsof` output?

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, I don't understand that part either. And if I comment the getOldestFile(); line, there are no leaks at all. Posted the lsof output snippet.

Comment: Ah, so it's not opening file descriptors for the files, but for the directories. You could correct that in your question.

Comment: @Thomas That was my bad. Corrected it now. The question still stands, though.

Comment: @Thomas I've managed to isolate the problem to one line, I've edited it above. Do you maybe know why that line is troublesome? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you are wasting memory and CPU resources with `Files.list(dir).collect(Collectors.toList()).size()` . You create a list only to find its size. How about `Files.list(dir).count()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`Files#list()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#list-java.nio.file.Path-):

> The returned stream encapsulates a `DirectoryStream`. If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.

Eventually, the stream will be garbage collected, but not immediately. So you have to manage it yourself in this case.

Comment: Using close() garbage collects it as it should. Thanks a lot.